# CruiseControl.NET - How to publish build once in a day at specific time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cruisecontrol.net

We have CC.NET as continuous integration environment. CC gets every commits from Git, build and publish to server.

This is config:

```
        <buildpublisher
            <sourceDir>Path_to_dir_with_source</sourceDir>
            <publishDir>path_to_deploy</publishDir>
            <cleanPublishDirPriorToCopy>true</cleanPublishDirPriorToCopy>
            <useLabelSubDirectory>false</useLabelSubDirectory>
            <alwaysPublish>true</alwaysPublish>
        </buildpublisher>
```

But our QA engeneer wants to get "fresh" build every morning, not 20 times in a day :)

Anybody know how to make this with CC.NET?

**[UPDATE]**

We still need to build every commit, but put this commit to web server only once in a day

Comment: http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Schedule_Trigger

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the ScheduleTrigger block:

```
<scheduleTrigger time="23:30" buildCondition="ForceBuild" name="Scheduled">
  <weekDays>
    <weekDay>Monday</weekDay>
  </weekDays>
</scheduleTrigger>
```

You can also use a cronTrigger, or an intervalTrigger, but for your case, the scheduleTrigger seems simplest.

http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Trigger_Blocks

**Added to address the comment:**

You can have multiple triggers in one Project block.

We have an Interval Trigger on our end as well as a Schedule Trigger.  You can have as many triggers as you need.

If you want to keep the builds separate, you can also have a compeltely separate Project block - one that operates on a Schedule trigger, and one that operates on an interval, but there are risks, and the configuration needs to be planned.  The following comes to mind as potential considerations:

1. If you do this, be sure you check out the source code to different directories, or you can run into conflicts if both are running at the same time.
2. Even if the source code checkout is to different directories, you can *still* run into conflicts if both projects are publishing to the same output location.

Comment: Thanks for answer i made one update to my question. is it change something in your answer?

Comment: @Evgeniy Labunskiy - I updated my answer because the response was too long for a comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made 2 project - one just build new commits, second build and publish

Answer (score 0):

You can add a schedule trigger that forces a build of your project at a specific time, i.e. the following would run a build every work-day at 5 am in the morning:

```
   <triggers>
      <scheduleTrigger time="05:00" buildCondition="ForceBuild">
        <weekDays>
            <weekDay>Monday</weekDay>
            <weekDay>Tuesday</weekDay>
            <weekDay>Wednesday</weekDay>
            <weekDay>Thursday</weekDay>
            <weekDay>Friday</weekDay>
        </weekDays>
      </scheduleTrigger>
   </triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer i made one update to my question. is it change something in your answer?